# Is there any way to edit the auto-increment value in sequalize PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js, auto-increment

Is there any way to edit the auto-increment value in sequalize PostgreSQL?
I want to edit the order value, is there any ways to edit it? As it is an auto-increment attribute I tried to update in pg admin it is not here is the query `update category set order = 22 where id = 2`.so someone please guide me 
    migration file :

```
'use strict';

    module.exports = {
        up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.createTable('category', {
                id: {
                    allowNull: false,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    primaryKey: true,
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                },
                media_id: {
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
                    allowNull: false,
                    onDelete: 'CASCADE',
                    references: {
                        model: 'media',
                        key: 'id',
                        as: 'media_id'
                    }
                },
                order: {
                    allowNull: false,
                    autoIncrement: true,
                    type: Sequelize.INTEGER
                },
                category_name: Sequelize.TEXT,
                created_at: {
                    allowNull: false,
                    type: Sequelize.DATE
                },
                updated_at: {
                    allowNull: false,
                    type: Sequelize.DATE
                }
            });
        },

        down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
            return queryInterface.dropTable('category');
        }
    };
```

model file

```
'use strict';
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Category = sequelize.define('Category', {
        media_id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            onDelete: 'CASCADE',
            references: {
                model: 'media',
                key: 'id',
                as: 'media_id'
            }
        },
        order: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER
        },
        latin_chars: DataTypes.STRING
    }, {
        underscored: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
        tableName: 'category'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it would be a sequence that you could locate in pgAdmin and then manipulate that sequence.. The database is what keeps track of where you are in your sequence, not sequelize